# Describe the blow-up of a zero scheme of a section of a vector bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Background:

> Let $X$ be a projective smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\scr{E}$ is a vector bundle of rank $c$ over $X$. Pick a global section $s\in H^0(\mathscr{E})$ such that its zero scheme $Y:=Z(s)\subset X$ is of codimension $c$. Now we need to discribe the blow-up $\mathrm{Bl}_{Y}X\to X$.

In the Page 252 in the book *Fourier-Mukai transform in AG* by D. Huybrechts, this described as follows:

> Consider $g:\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})\to X$ and its Euler sequence
> $$
> 0\to\mathscr{O}_g(-1)\to g^*\mathscr{E}\stackrel{\phi}{\to}T_g\otimes\mathscr{O}_g(-1)\to0.
> $$
> Consider $t=\phi(g^*(s))\in H^0(\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E}),T_g\otimes\mathscr{O}_g(-1))$ and they claim that $g$ induce $Z(t)=\mathrm{Bl}_{Y}X\to X$. Why?

Now we know $g^{-1}(Y)\subset Z(t)$ and from some analysis in local I can show that $g$ induce a **bijection** on $\mathbb{C}$-points of $Z(t)\backslash g^{-1}(Y)\to X\backslash Y$. As $X$ is smooth, by Zariski main theorem we can show that $Z(t)\backslash g^{-1}(Y)\to X\backslash Y$ is an isomorphism. Now $\mathrm{codim}_{Z(t)}(g^{-1}(Y))=1$.

(I) Is this enough to show $Z(t)=\mathrm{Bl}_{Y}X\to X$? Maybe we need to use the universal property of blow-up?

(II) By a result in Hartshorne's AG book, $Z(t)\to X$ must be a blow-up morphism. Hence $f:Z(t)=\mathrm{Bl}_{Y'}X$ where $Y'$ is a subscheme of $X$ with the same topology space as $Y$. We just need to show $Y'$ is reduced.

Using the proof of that result, if we let the ample line bundle of $X$ is $\mathscr{L}$ and let the $f$-ample line bundle $\mathscr{M}$,
then there exists $n$ such that $\mathscr{L}^{-n}f_* \mathscr{M}\subset\mathscr{O}$ and $Y'$ is defined by $\mathscr{I}:=\mathscr{L}^{-n}f_* \mathscr{M}$. How can I do next?

---

Thank you for your any help!!!

Comment: I think you need to assume that $Y$ is smooth (this is what is assumed in Huybrecht's book). In that case, $Y$ is regularly immersed in $X$ and the result is proven in SGA6, VII.1.8 (ii), p. 425.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you very much!